# Good expressions to signify extensive analysis

Tags: phrase-requests, quotes, popular-refrains

I am looking for a way to communicate in a business context that I am carrying out extensive analysis to get to the bottom of something by synthesizing info and insights from various sources to come up with an insightful and clear viewpoint.

The analysis could be described as deep dive, but I am looking for a more profound / sagelike way to express this process (could also be a quote).

Comment: If I were trying to sound important I might mention a "comprehensive analysis" or an "investigation into the underlying factors." Speaking frankly, I would admit I just looked up the origins of Esperanto on Wikipedia, but in my defense sometimes Esperanto *is* an underlying factor.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **[dissection](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dissection)**

> a critical and minute examination  - *her calm, condescending dissection of my proposals*

Or possibly **[scrutiny](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrutiny)**

> close or minute examination